# converting date time format in sql

Tags: sql-server

i have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[startandenddtime]
@startdate nvarchar(100)
as begin 
declare @date3 nvarchar(100) = cast(CONVERT(varchar(100), @startdate + ' 16:59:59',      120) as datetime)
select date3  as startdate
end
```

If i pass my startdate as 2013-05-08 i am getting out put as  :
[image]
but i want to get out put as `2013-05-08 16:59:59.000`..so how i can convert this format 
is this date time i can store in nvarchar varibale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
 DECLARE @StartDate NVARCHAR(100)='2013-05-08'
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@StartDate+'16:59:59', 121)
```

[MORE](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19485)**

Comment: i given like this:declare @date3 nvarchar(100) = convert(varchar, @startdate+' 00:00:00.000', 120) now i got my expected out put..thank for sharing link

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[startandenddtime]
@startdate nvarchar(100)
as begin 
declare @date3 nvarchar(100) = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),@startdate ,121)) as datetime)
select date3  as startdate
end
```

For more in details see this, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select cast(CONVERT(varchar(100), @startdate + ' 16:59:59') as date)
```

Or

```
Select cast(CONVERT(varchar(100), @startdate + ' 16:59:59') as datetime)
```

Comment: but this time only date is getting ..i want get time also

Comment: while passing your second query am getting my same out put

Answer (score 0):

Just don't cast varchar value to datetime

edit: If you don't get what i meant in my comment:

```
convert(varchar, convert(datetime, @startdate + ' 16:59:59', 120), 120)
```

Comment: i want to store that datetime into varchar variable

Comment: SP param is nvarchar. You concatenate nvarchars and then cast result into `datetime` just to store it as `nvarchar` again. If you want to store it in your chosen format just add one more `convert(varchar(100), <datetime>, 120)` after casting to datetime or drop casting altogether (you can't be sure wheter string contains proper datetime then)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Declare @dt varchar(20);
Declare @startdate varchar(20)='2013-05-08';
SET @dt= CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(datetime,@startdate+' 16:59:59'), 100)
Select @dt;
```